# The details about the value returned by QWidget::winId() changing at runtime

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

`QWidget::winId()` is used to return the underlying OS-specific handle of the window that the widget is contained in.  In the documentation, it states:

> This value may change at run-time. An event with type `QEvent::WinIdChange` will be sent to the widget following a change in window system identifier.

This makes it sounds like it is unsafe to store the returned variable directly (at least without having some mechanism that listens to the event and updates the variable).

However, I have wired up a event filter that does that exact thing, and it has never actually been called.

This has me thinking that this is either the result of some weird edge cases, or is specific to some operating systems.

What are the underlying mechanisms that cause the window id to change?  Does it effect all operating systems?  Are there any set of assumptions that would make it safe to store and later use the window id?

For this case, the window id is just being used to see if a list of windows from the OS contains the specified id returned by the `winId()` function.

Comment: I can't speak for Qt, as I've never used it, but in some other frameworks, like VCL, it is certainly possible for the framework to recreate a window handle dynamically during a control's lifetime, such as when applying certain new property values to the window.  And when a window is destroyed/recreated, any child windows it has also have to be destroyed/recreated, too.  A control's lifetime, and its window handle's lifetime, are related, but handled at separate layers (framework and OS, respectively).